# Having trouble with "Rectangles"

Tags: java

> Create a class Rectangle with instance variables length and width to
>   have default value of 1 for both of them. The class should have
>   suitable set and get methods for accessing its instance variables. The
>   set    methods should verify that length and width are assigned a
>   value that is larger than 0.0 and is lesser than 20.0, Provide
>   suitable public methods to calculate the rectangle’s perimeter and
>   area. Write a suitable class "RectangleTest" to test the Rectangle
>   class.

What I came up with:

```
package rectangle;
public class Rectangle
{
    private double width;
    private double length;
    public Rectangle()
    {
    width=1;
    length=1;
    }
    public Rectangle(double width, double length)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }
    public void setWidth(float width)
    {      
        this.width = width;        
    }
    public float getWidth()
    {
        return (float) width;
    }
    public void setLength(float length)
    {
        this.length = length;
    }
    public float getLength()
    {
        return (float) length;
    }
    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return 2 * (width + length);
    }
    public double getArea()
    {
        return width * length;
    }   
}
```

---

```
package rectangle;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RectangleTest extends Rectangle 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {               
        Scanner RectangleTest = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Length: ");
        float lengthInput = RectangleTest.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Width: ");
        float widthInput = RectangleTest.nextFloat();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle (lengthInput, widthInput);
        System.out.printf("Perimeter: %f%n",
        rectangle.getPerimeter());
        System.out.printf("Area: %f%n",
        rectangle.getArea());        
    }   
}
```

Code is fine, it's just I am not sure how to implement the between 0 - 20 without breaking everything and have tried different things.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check it and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the value isn't valid, e.g.:

```
public void setLength(float length) {
    if (length <= 0f || length >= 20.0f) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid length " + length);
    }
    this.length = length;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, it continues to ignore everything. Is it because the code has to be in the " public static void main(String[] args)". or am i just stupid and should give up on programming?

Comment: What specifically didn't work about it? Did you not get an exception thrown? Are you actually getting the right values in your 'length' variable? Have you tried printing progress via System.out.println() (and including your input values?)